# unix shell - ls -d $PWD

Tags: shell, unix, ls

I would like to make an alias called Ls which prints out the current directory and file name when I try to list a specific file

```
unix> ls a.txt
unix> a.txt -> print out

I want it to print out the directory name too:

unix> /hier1/hier2/hier3/a.txt

When I do 'ls -d $PWD/a.txt'
it prints out

unix> /hier1/hier2/hier3/a.txt

When I make an alias of the above

alias Ls 'ls -d $PWD', it prints out the as below with a space.

unix> Ls a.txt
unix> /hier1/hier2/hier3 a.txt 

How do I get the below print without the space and with a slash as below:

unix> Ls a.txt
unix> /hier1/hier2/hier3/a.txt -> THIS IS WHAT I WANT
```

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, read the descriptions of the tags that you applied to get an idea why your question in and of itself is flawed.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support.

Comment: I think you'd be better off writing a script to do this than trying to do this with an alias.  Additionally, writing a script should be on topic for this site.

Comment: yes, write a script, or declare your script as a function in `.bashrc` or one of the other `.` files that `bash` sources. You have to trick an alias to work with a changeable argument, and when you decide, "oh I need one more feature to be really happy", then you need to write a function anyway. (Where do people keep getting the idea that aliases are the first line of solutions?! ;-)! ) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias Ls="echo -n $PWD/; ls $1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are better off making a function. Go into your ~/.bashrc file and create the function as such with the export command:

```
function Ls(){
    p="$PWD" 
    out="${p}/${1}"
    echo $out
}
```

Then save and quit *:wq*, and type in:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And the command should be ready to go

**If you are using zsh, then add:**

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

to the ~/.zshrc file.